# Upper and lower bound on the N-th Pythagorean triplet

Tags: number-theory, inequality, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Let $H_n$ be the hypotenuse of the $n$-th primitive Pythagorean Triplet when arranged in ascending order of the length of the hypotenuse. What is known about the asymptotic expansion of or bounds on $H_n$?

My experimental data suggests that

$$
2\pi n - 4n^{\frac{1}{3}} - 4 < H_n < 2\pi n + 4n^{\frac{1}{3}} + 4
$$

There are no violations of this inequality for $n \le 1.4 \times 10^8$.

Comment: The $2\pi n$ is well known - for example in [OEIS A020882](https://oeis.org/A020882) and in [D. N. Lehmer, Asymptotic evaluation of certain totient sums, Amer. J. Math. 22 (1900), 293–335](https://archive.org/details/jstor-2369728/page/n35/mode/2up).  Looking at the first $10^5$ cases, your $\pm ( 4n^{\frac{1}{3}} + 4)$ looks fairly arbitrary to fit for example the $n=6996$ case - is it anything more than this?

Comment: @Henry While the dominant term $2\pi n$ is know the $\pm (4n^{\frac{1}{3}} + 4)$ was based on the normality of distribution of the gap $H_n - 2\pi n$ and its standard deviation. I will post an update on this.

Answer (score 2):

A [graph of hypotenuse values](https://oeis.org/A020882/graph) shows that they are very very close to $\space  2\pi n.\space $
There are $\space 2^{−1}\space $ primitive triples for every $\space _\space $ where $\space \space $ is the number of distinct prime factors of $\space _. \space$
If you allow for these multiple triples for some $\space _\space $ values:
$\quad (6-1)\le H_n \le (7-1)\quad$